# Unable to read the Server response messages when WSAECONNRESET error is encountered?

Tags: tcp, client-server, cross-platform, winsock

Working on a client application (running on windows) problem which uses asynchronous communication (with sockets) with the database server (running on linux).

The client application hit with WSAECONNRESET error while loading data to the server and the server terminates the socket. I have used the WSAGetLastError function and extracted the error message. *The server had send some messages (reporting application specific error message) to the client before terminating the socket with WSAECONNRESET error.*  The client is unable to extract the last message which is sent by the server (as the socket is closed and "recv" function fails). My question is **how to extract the last messages sent by the database server (on linux) to client(on windows) ?**

Please note, this case is working fine with linux database server to linux client. I mean, unix socket to unix socket.  But problem occurs only with linux socket to windows socket communication.

Appreciate your help Please !!

Comment: I've added the TCP tag, hopefully one of the experts will chime in.  But [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination) you are breaking the rules by closing the connection before the client has confirmed receipt of the error message.

Comment: @HarryJohnston He is breaking the rules by *resetting* the connection. Closing it properly can only have that effect if there is unread data The statement in Wikipedia is not correct. Was* not  correct: I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. 'Connection reset' destroys the connection, and all in-flight data is lost, including any that may be already buffered at the receiver.

You need to fix the problem that causes the reset.

Comment: Just mentioning again...the code is working fine with linux server to linux client.  But fails with linux server to windows clients (cross platform). As per my knowledge, the behavior and handling of the socket in windows and linux differ a bit. I mean to say that socket is just a file descriptor in linux, but it is not the case with windows.  Please correct me, if I am wrong. I believe that there must be a way to read the last message from the server (which it send before closing the socket).  Yes, I totally agree with you all that when the socket closes no data is accessible.

Comment: The server placed the error messages in the buffer before it closed the socket.  When linux client could read the messages successfully with "recv" call, why can't the windows client do it?  There must be a way to do it.  Somehow, I am missing that !!

Comment: If I understand what EJP is saying correctly, the problem might be elsewhere in the code.  For example, perhaps there's a bug in the Windows client that means it is sending more data than it should, and the server isn't reading that data; apparently, that would change the close into a reset and cause the error messages to be discarded.  Perhaps you'd better provide a [mcve].

Comment: @user_2011 The client can't do it because, as I have already told you, 'connection reset ' throws away all data in flight, including any that is already buffered at the receiver. Fix the reset and you fix that too. But you can't magically change the semantics of reset. The server is probably closing the connection with unread data, or else it is deliberately resetting the connection, which is rare but not unknown.

Comment: I thank you all for your suggestions. Thanks EJP in specific.